# Getter not invoked when chained in multiple assign operator

Tags: javascript, typescript

When I use multiple assignment operator such as `a = b = c` and `b` is a getter/setter, the setter is invoked perfectly but getter not; why?

Here's a simple example:

```
//define simple example class to describe the situation
export class GetterSetter
{
private m_sValue:string = '';

    constructor ()
    {
    }

    public get value (): string
    {
        return this.m_sValue;
    }

    private set value (val:string)
    {
        this.m_sValue = (val ?? '').trim();
    }

    public getValue1 (): string
    {
    let ret:string = this.value;
        this.value = null!;
        ret = this.value;
        return ret;
    }

    public getValue2 (): string
    {
    let ret:string = this.value;
        ret = this.value = null!;
        return ret;
    }
}

//invocation
const obj:GetterSetter = new GetterSetter();
const s1:string = obj.getValue1();
const s2:string = obj.getValue2();
```

getValue1() works as expected. getValue2() produces null. In getValue2() the setter is invoked twice as expected but the getter never invoked.

For getValue2() I expected the getter to be invoked for this line:
`ret = this.value = null!;`
but it was not. It happens both in debugger and in production.

Comment: You will most likely find your answer here https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/ecmascript-language-expressions.html#sec-assignment-operators

Comment: The [assignment operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Assignment) `y = x` both *assigns* `x` to `y`, and *evaluates* to `x`.  It never reads from `x`.  A compound assignment like `z = (y = x)` is equivalent to `let temp = (y = x)` followed by `z = temp`.  At no point does anything read from `y`.  Does that fully address your question?  If so I could write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz That's what I got from the ECMAScript standard, but I don't quite understand how the `value` property in the question is _evaluated_ without being read. What does evaluation mean versus reading?

Comment: It is not evaluated.  The left hand side is only written to, never read or evaluated.  Let me try to explain it this way: `y = x` only ever evaluates `x`.  It assigns `x` to `y`, and it also returns `x`.  It never ever ever evaluates or reads from `y`.  Does that make sense now?

Comment: You're thinking `z = (y = x)` behaves like "`x` is assigned to `y` and then `y` is assigned to `z`", but it doesn't.  It really behaves like "`x` is assigned to both `y` and `z`".  Let me know if I can write this up as an answer or if it's still not making sense.

Comment: That definitely makes sense, I just had the wrong assumption

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [JavaScript assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Assignment) expression `y = x` *evaluates* to its right-hand side, so `y = x` can be thought of as just `x`.  But it also has the *effect* of assigning the right-hand side to the variable/property on the left-hand side.  So after `y = x` is done, `x` has been assigned to `y`.  Note that nowhere in that description is `y` ever *evaluated* or *read from*; it is only *written to*.  Code that only triggers when `y` is read from will not trigger.

In a compound statement like `z = y = x`, or the equivalent `z = (y = x)`, first the inner assignment `y = x` happens, which assigns `x` to `y` and evaluates to `x`.  Then the outer assignment happens, which assigns `x` to `z` (and also evaluates to `x` but that is simply discarded).  Again, at no point is `y` (or `z` for that matter) ever *read*, so any code triggered by reading `y` will stay untriggered.

So there you go.  `z = y = x` does *not* behave like "`x` is assigned to `y` and then `y` is assigned to `z`".  Instead, it behaves like "`x` is assigned to both `y` and `z`".